# Where can I get the official Chromium .deb package?

Tags: chromium

Before I had installed Chromium 20 from wolf\crack PPA, but later I had uninstalled it when I know it is not an official PPA.

I found it at the [Ubuntu package repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/i386/chromium-browser/) for download, I think its official version, but when I install it with the software center it still downloads the version 20, should I trust it?

---

I had tried to install Chromium from the chromium-browser_20.0.1132.47~r144678-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_i386.deb which I had downloaded in my computer, but the Ubuntu Software Center download it again and by checking the 2 downloaded files md5, I found them is not the same, is it fine?

Answer (score 7):

You can simply open a terminal (CTRL+ALT+T) then type `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser`, press the Enter key, type your usual login password (the password will not be echoed to screen as you type, for security reasons), then hit the Enter key and this way you'll install the official build of the Chromium web browser.

My Chromium version is **Version 20.0.1132.47 Ubuntu 12.04 (144678)** - and I installed it using the method above.

Comment: Correct. The Chromium browser included in main Ubuntu repositories. This is the official Chromium version for Ubuntu. Also you can find it in Ubuntu Software Center if you don't want to use the terminal.

Comment: I think that this answer is NOT correct because that way you install the snappy version of the chromium along with the snapd daemon.
Also running chromium from snappy breaks the chromium in the following ways: You don't have access to your /tmp folder, you can't use DBUS and start external applications (for example conf calls)

Answer (score 3):

**If you are looking for a .deb (not snap) package for Ubuntu 20.04+**

You can download latest official .deb build for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal), 21.04 (Hirsute) and 21.10 (Impish) here:
[https://launchpad.net/~phd/+archive/ubuntu/chromium-browser/](https://launchpad.net/%7Ephd/+archive/ubuntu/chromium-browser/)

This is a PPA repository with **official Ubuntu packages** released originally for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Bionic) and updated as soon as a new version is released.

UPDATE:

Since April 2023 Canonical does no longer provide
Chromium .deb packages for any version of Ubuntu.
Hence THIS REPOSITORY WILL NO LONGER BE UPDATED.
**You may want to switch to:**
https://freeshell.de/phd/chromium

Answer (score 2):

Open terminal and Type following commands to install Chromium .

```
sudo add-apt-key ppa:chromium-daily/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

If you want to get Chrome browser you can get .deb package [here](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/).

Comment: I only got `add-apt-key: command not found`

Answer (score 1):

#### This answer is no longer valid, the PPA is not up-to-date. Just follow Clive's answer above, it was always the better choice anyway

---

Chromium 20 is indeed in the official repositories. You can download it through terminal (see other answer) or through the software center. Adding a separate PPA for version 20 is unnecessary.

If you want the most updated stable release (or daily builds for that matter), however, you should add a PPA. I did so and am currently using version 22.

For the latest stable version, go to Terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:a-v-shkop/chromium
sudo apt-get update
```

If you haven't installed Chromium yet, also run `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser`

See [this article on Webupd8.org](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/new-chromium-stable-and-development.html) for more information.

Comment: Currently Google don't update the 'chromium-daily' repository for unknown reasons. 'a-v-shkop' guy promised to keep packaging the browser until he's bored enough to stop cheering us :)

Comment: The repo `ppa:a-v-shkop` seems to be gone.

Comment: Thanks @Nenotlep. Seems like the PPA is [still there](https://launchpad.net/~a-v-shkop/+archive/ubuntu/chromium), but not being updated. My answer is out of date.